# I can't debug native code running .NET assemblies in VS 2012 anymore

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a Delphi application that loads some .NET assemblies which I want to debug. I don't want to debug the Delphi code, just the .NET assemblies.

In VS 2010, all I had to do was to make the output directory of my .NET code to point to the Delphi executable folder and set up `Start external program` to point to executable path. When I hit F5, it automatically started the Delphi code, loaded the modules and I was ready to debug.

Now I migrated to VS 2012. I do the same but the debug does not work. The process starts and it is correctly attached but the Modules window is completely empty. No symbols loaded. I can't debug anything.

Is there anything special I must do to make it to work in VS 2012?

Comment: You've enabled unmanaged code debugging?

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan "Enable unmanaged code debugging" is not marked. I thought it was there to allow me to debug the Delphi code itself. I'm gonna enable it to see what happens

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan Now the Modules window is filled with a lot of modules. But the specific .NET module I want to debug is showing "No native symbols in symbol file" and my breakpoints are marked as "No symbols have been loaded"

Comment: Hmm. In all honesty I misread the question initially... But anyway.. What .net version are your assemblies?

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan 3.5.. all of them

Comment: And there are pdb files accompanying the .net assemblies?

Comment: Yes, and it is stated in the Modules window when I click in "show module properties" (not sure the name). But in the breakpoint itself it says no symbols have been loaded. I'm not sure I can do anything. Thank you jdv, for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Wait! Maybe you should check that your fake project is a .net 3.5 (or 2.0) project. That's a different implementation of the runtime. If you "attach to a running process" you can check separate boxes for 4.0 .net versius 2.0 (.net 3.5 internally uses the 2.0 clr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the EXACT same scenario as yours (hope its not too late).

The problem was that while in "Attach Process" you could select the .NET version of the debugger (in our case Managed 3-3.5) when you start an external program the default debugger for some reason is 4.
What to do: File>Add>Existing Project, and add the basic EXE file of your unmanaged program. It will appear as a single file project. Right click it and "Set as startup project". Right click again and Properties. set Debugger type : Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0).

That's it, the debugger will now load the correct version. I am positive this will work out just fine.

Comment: I would never think for adding a native executable as a project in my solution. Thank you!

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much! It has worked for me. I'm wondering, how did you manage to figure this out.

Comment: A great deal of luck, and persistance, as far as I recall :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the exact same problem.  Running MMC.exe with a .NET 3.5 snapin.  Debugged fine before upgrading to VS2012, now after upgrade it says there are no native symbols loaded and breakpoints don't work.  @jdv-JandeVaan hint was what I needed to move ahead.  I needed to set the debugger to use .NET 3.5.  The only way I could find to do that was to select .NET 3.5 in the Attach to Process... dialog.  Inconvenient but it works.